# Opening a new window by clicking <p:commandButton> in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to open a new pop up window by clicking a button `<p:commandButton>` in JSF.

Here is my code,

```
<h:inputText style="width:42%"value="#{xxbean.values}" rendered="#{xxBean.yy == true}" 
     onblur="cc;" maxlength="6">
</h:inputText> 
<p:commandButton value="FindPhone" id="xxne" actionListener="#{xx.findPhoneSearch}"
    oncomplete="window.open('#{xx.wpUrl}', '_blank')" 
    rendered="#{xx.editCmdActionflg == true }"  async="false">
    <f:param name="pmid" value="#{xx.Details.uid}"/>                                   
</p:commandButton>
```

I am calling he method findPhoneSearch like the one given above in actionlistener inside the command button ,

Here is the findPhoneSearch method ,

```
public void FindphoneSearch(ActionEvent event) {



        String param = "";

        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String expression = "^[a-z0-9]+$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);

        if (params.get("pmid") != null) {
            String t_pmid = params.get("pmid");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t_pmid);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                param = "/cgi-bin/Findphones.pl?id=" + t_pmid.trim();
            }
        }

        if (params.get("lpid") != null) {
            String t_lpid = params.get("lpid");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t_lpid);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                param = "/cgi-bin/Findphones.pl?id=" + t_lpid.trim();
            }
        }

        String findphoneUrl= "http://Findphone.com" + param;
        wpUrl = findphoneUrl;


    }
```

My problem is the window is open blank without passing the url that I am framing which is assigned in wpurl.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try adding the attribute update="@all" to your commandButton. I believe your problem is that you are trying to use ajax calls without updating your view with the answer, so the value of wpUrl is old (empty).

Comment: @yamada: I tried that too but its not helping.I am trying to pass the parameters to backing bean using this code <f:param name="pmid"    value="#{xx.Details.uid}"/> when i click the command button,  but I could not able to get the value.

Comment: You can use onclick="target='_blank'" https://stackoverflow.com/a/54010074/5626568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EL `#{...}` in `oncomplete` attribute of a PrimeFaces component is evaluated when the page with the button is displayed for the first time, not after the button is pressed. So basically, you're dealing with the value as it was while the page is rendered, not with the value which is changed in action method.

You'd better ajax-update an inline script instead of performing `oncomplete`.

```
<p:commandButton ... update="openWindow" />
<h:panelGroup id="openWindow">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{not empty xx.wpUrl}">
        window.open('#{xx.wpUrl}', '_blank')
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Don't forget to remove `async="false"` from the button.